# windows 10 cmd can´t find the file "eslint"

Tags: reactjs, webpack, eslint

I´m trying to acces throw cmd of windows 10, to the file eslint for set Eslint with "eslint --init" command. But suddenly the following error message appears:

```
cd : Cannot find path 'eslint' because it does not exist.
At line:1 char:1
+ cd eslint
+ ~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (eslint:String) [Set-    
Location], ItemNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId :     
PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetLocationCommand
```

I don´t understand why is that, because the file exist in following path "node_modules/.bin":

```
-a----        2/19/2018  11:49 AM            192 babylon.cmd
-a----        2/19/2018  11:51 AM            309 browserslist
-a----        2/19/2018  11:51 AM            186 browserslist.cmd
-a----        2/19/2018  11:51 AM            305 cssesc
-a----        2/19/2018  11:51 AM            182 cssesc.cmd
-a----        2/19/2018  11:51 AM            297 csso
-a----        2/19/2018  11:51 AM            174 csso.cmd
-a----        2/19/2018  11:45 AM            295 errno
-a----        2/19/2018  11:45 AM            172 errno.cmd
-a----        2/24/2018  11:59 AM            311 eslint
-a----        2/24/2018  11:59 AM            188 eslint.cmd
-a----        2/19/2018  11:51 AM            315 esparse
-a----        2/19/2018  11:51 AM            192 esparse.cmd
```

Comment: You cannot `cd` into a regular file, only into a directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Windows, with `cd`command you can only go into directories. If you want to show file details you can use `more file_name`.